# children route not working

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I'm trying to learn angular2 and doing sample app.

I want to make that when i click on service1 it must display some list and when i click to one of them i want to redirect into child route to edit that name.

When I'm clicking to service1 it throws that error:

[image]

and of course after that nothing works

here's my `app.routing.ts`

```
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppHomeComponent } from './app.home-component';

import { ServicesComponent } from './service1/services.component';
import { Service2Component } from './service2/service2.component';
import { ServiceDetailComponent } from './service1/service-detail.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'apphomecomponent',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: 'apphomecomponent',
        component: AppHomeComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'service1',
        component: ServicesComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                component: ServicesComponent
            },
            {
                path: 'service1/:id',
                component: ServiceDetailComponent
            }

        ]
    },

    {
        path: 'service2',
        component: Service2Component
    }
];

export const appRouting: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

`service-detail.component.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ServicesService } from './services.service';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
    selector: 'service-detail',
    template: '{{service.name}}'
})

export class ServiceDetailComponent implements OnInit {
    sub: any;
    service: any;


    constructor(private servicesService: ServicesService, private route: ActivatedRoute) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
            let id = +params['id'];
            this.service = this.servicesService.getServiceById(id);
        });
    }
}
```

and `services.component.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ServicesService } from './services.service';
import { Service } from './service';
import { Route } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
    selector: 'services',
    templateUrl: 'app/service1/services.html',
    providers: [ServicesService]
})

export class ServicesComponent implements OnInit {
    services: Service[];

    constructor(private servicesService: ServicesService) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.services = this.servicesService.getServices();
    }
}
```

What's wrong? or where can I find solution?

`services.html` looks:

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let service of services">
        <a [routerLink]="['/service', service.id]">{{service.name}}</a>
    </li>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</ul>
```

my folder structure is:

[image]

Comment: @PankajParkar thanks but error logs before I click to for example `DEA`. it logs when I'm clicking to service1. I changed `service1/:id` to `:id` but result is same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error says **It can not find primary outlet to load servicescomponent**. It means you are missing with **`<router-outlet>`**.

Where you display list of items, below that just put **`<router-outlet></router-outlet>`** and it will start working as it requires to load **servicescomponent** through router.

also change routes to below,

```
{
    path: 'service1',
    component: ServicesComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: ':id',
            component: ServiceDetailComponent
        }

    ]
},
```

You need to also change,

```
<a [routerLink]="['/service', service.id]">{{service.name}}</a>
```

to

```
<a [routerLink]="['/service1', service.id]">{{service.name}}</a>
```

Comment: I told you to modify your routes check in answer.

Comment: when i delete '' path from children route it don't even go inside of service1. error is `Error: Cannot match any routes: 'service1'` and so on.